# unix - copy modified source file to destination file

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I want to change some text in source file and put it in the destination file using unix.
Using `sed` i can do

```
sed -i 's/FIND TEXT/REPLACE TEXT/g' source.txt
```

But this replaces the text in the same file. I want something like

```
sed -i 's/FIND TEXT/REPLACE TEXT/g' source.txt dest.txt
```

where the `source.txt` is not modified but the changes are there in `dest.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So then don't do it in-place.

```
sed 's/FIND TEXT/REPLACE TEXT/g' source.txt > dest.txt
```

Comment: thanks. this works. How do I modify this so that i can replace multiple texts. For example, `sed 's/FIND TEXT1/REPLACE TEXT1/g' source.txt > dest.txt` and `sed 's/FIND TEXT2/REPLACE TEXT2/g' source.txt > dest.txt`. In a script file if I try to do this one by one then when I execute the 2nd command the changes in first are lost

Comment: Perform both commands in a single invocation. `sed 's/FIND TEXT1/REPLACE TEXT1/g;s/FIND TEXT2/REPLACE TEXT2/g' source.txt > dest.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Doing the same with `awk`

```
awk '{gsub(/FIND TEXT1/,"REPLACE TEXT1");gsub(/FIND TEXT2/,"REPLACE TEXT2")}1' source.txt > dest.txt
```

`gsub()` replaces all text it find

`1` does print all line after the replace has been done.